# How do I specify page to display at the beginning in controller

Tags: php, pagination, laravel-5.7

I have a paginate like :

```
//Controller (UserController)

public show(){

    $users = DB::table('user')->paginate(15);
    return view('user');
}

public process(Request $request){
    //something update
    return $this->show();
}

//View (user.blade.php)

<head>
    <script>
        //submit user's id and name to UserController@process 
    </script>
</head>
<body>
{{ $users->link() }}
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>userName</th>
            <th>modifly</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach($users as $user)
            <tr>
                <td><input type="text" value="{{ $user->name }}"</td>
                <td><input type="submit" value="modifly"></td>
            </tr>
        @endforeach
    </tbody>
</table>
</body>
```

When I submit a request at 3rd page , It will show 1st page just like I view('user') at first , but I need show the currentPage page after I submit.

How do I pass 3rd page($users->currentPage()) to DB::table('user')->paginate(15) and view('user') with currentPage  when I submit a request at 3rd page?

Answer (score 0):

in your submit action pass currentpage as queryparameter, then in your controller,

```
$page=$request->input('queryname');
// do update here
return redirect('/your/url?page='.$page);
```

use return redirect instead return $this->show();

Comment: Thanks for your answer!
But I need  return $this->show() to do somthing update the  Database.

Comment: `redirect('url?page='.$page)` will do the same thing with `$this->show();` the different is it will go to spesific page based on you queryparameter. if you want to do update, write the code before redirect

Answer (score 0):

Submit the page number in the form for example as follows:

```
//Controller (UserController)

public show(Request $request){
    $returnValues = array();
    $users = DB::table('user')->paginate(15);
    $returnValues['users'] = $users;
    $returnValues['page'] = 1;
    if ($request->has('page'))
        $returnValues['page'] = $request->input('page');
    return view('user', $returnValues);
}

public process(Request $request){
    //something update
    return $this->show($request);
}

//View (user.blade.php)

<head>
    <script>
        $('#pagesContainer a').on('click',function () {

            var page = $(this).attr("href").split('page=')[1];
            $('#pageNumber').val(page);
            $('input[type=submit]').click();
            return false;

    }) 
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="pagesContainer">
{{ $users->link() }}
</div>
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>userName</th>
            <th>modifly</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach($users as $user)
            <tr>
                <td><input type="text" value="{{ $user->name }}"</td>
                <td>
                    <input type="hidden" name="page" id="pageNumber" value="{{ $page }}">
                    <input type="submit" value="modifly">
                </td>

            </tr>
        @endforeach
    </tbody>
</table>
</body>
```

However, depending on the number of forms on your page, it may require a little bit of changes